# mayusculas a minusculas punteros

Tags: c++, punteros

estaba haciendo este codigo de c++ con punteros pero por alguna razon compila pero al mostrar la palabra mayuscula en minuscula no muestra nada y si trato de hacerlo al revez, es decir la minuscula a mayuscula me salen signos de interrogacion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
void mayus(char*);
int main()
{
    char pala[50];
    cout<<"Digite la palabra a transformar: ";
    cin.getline(pala, 50);
    cout<<"La palabra anteriormente era: " <<pala<<endl;
    mayus(pala);
    cout<<"Ahora la palabra es: "<<pala<<endl;

    return 0;
}
void mayus(char*letra){
while (*letra!='\0'){
    if(toupper(*letra)){
        *letra=islower(*letra);
        letra++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Solo por el nombre de las funciones, diría que las tienes intercambiadas. `islower( )` debería estar como expresión en el `if( )`, y `toupper( )` en la asignación.

Answer (score 0):

El código que presentas es erróneo a varios niveles:

- **Algoritmo**: Usas en condiciones funciones de transformación (`toupper`) y usas en asignaciones funciones de decisión (`islower`).

  En C++ los valores numéricos se convierten implícitamente a expresiones booleanas siendo cero equivalente a "*falso*" y cualquier otro valor equivalente a "*verdadero*", así que al usar la función `toupper` (que transforma un carácter a mayúscula) siempre obtendrás un valor diferente a cero ("*verdadero*") lo que implica que esta comprobación **siempre** se cumple:

  ```
  if(toupper(*letra)){ // Esto siempre es verdadero.
  ```

  Los caracteres imprimibles empiezan en el valor 32 (espacio:  ), cualquier otro valor o no se imprimirá o actuará de manera *extraña*. La función `islower` devuelve cero si el parámetro no es una letra minúscula o un valor indeterminado diferente a cero (probablemente uno) si la letra es minúscula; por eso si guardas el valor devuelto por `islower` dentro de una variable que imprimirás luego, muy probablemente no verás nada:

  ```
  *letra=islower(*letra);
  ```
- **Lenguaje**: Mezclas cabeceras del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) pero programas en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), las cabeceras `<stdio.h>` y `<string.h>` no deben usarse programando en C++.
- **Buenas prácticas**: En C++ moderno el uso de punteros está desaconsejado. El bucle `while` por convención se usa en casos en que se desconozca el número de iteraciones y se desaconseja el uso de la cláusula `using namespace std` en ámbitos globales.

Si corregimos todos tus errores, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

void mayus(std::string &);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string pala;
    cout << "Digite la palabra a transformar: ";
    getline(cin, pala);

    cout << "La palabra anteriormente era: " << pala << endl;
    mayus(pala);

    cout << "Ahora la palabra es: " << pala << endl;

    return 0;
}

void mayus(std::string &palabra) {
    for (auto &c : palabra)
        c = toupper(c);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdasMwDIWvo6cQHZQENth1khUGu9xLaI6WGRLZ2PKgjD57prQdDWyzL2x0jj79uBgf3EQyLsudFzeVgbH3IWtimg9wizmnx8jbiHm8jAeAz@AHnOlYcp11aNuLgPumA/CiJnmpG/iCquRVEJo5R3KMZjdPdU2INFEHlQtFse9x9@JHr4wTnZW3REioiSS/hzRTanFn7pF18sK183J/9q1Vb4zXTbIoJ2@pbB/kRAZYPau@vizDZMDLIL9Jzx/BIJtmOP8JALSTWEsSfOzg9P9@rqAGbTM2EtZUNODeYftTo4GqcviEGkqMnGpnLZ2WJZLahW8)</kbd>.